# Salvar arquivo txt com codificação windows

Tags: php, arquivo, unix

Minha aplicação roda em um SO Unix, sendo assim, meus arquivos `.TXT` são criados no formato UNIX, preciso que estes arquivos sejam criados no formato WINDOWS.

Preciso que as quebras de linhas sejam no formato WINDOWS \r\n. Estou com problema com o formato UNIX porque ele insere somente o \n.

Hoje, crio os arquivos usando `file_put_contents`.

Comment: Pode descrever melhor? O que exatamente quer mudar no formato? Quebras de linha? Charset (acentuação)? Por favor, seja mais específico.

Comment: acho que ele se refere a quebras de linha

Comment: Isso, eu me refiro a quebra de linhas. Preciso que as quebras de linhas sejam no formato WINDOWS \r\n.
Estou com problema com o formato UNIX porque ele insere somente o \n.

Comment: @DaniloOliveira és tu que estás a escrever nos ficheiros? Se sim basta escreveres o \r\n.

Comment: @JorgeB, sim,  sou eu que estou estou escrevendo. Escrever \r\n não funciona, já fiz este teste.

Answer (score 1):

Para isso basta que sempre que guarde alguma coisa no arquivo que já vá com a formatação correta, usando a função [iconv](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.iconv.php):

```
<?php

$dados = "Eu não conseguia guardar texto em formato windows e agora já consigo.";

// Alterar o enconding do texto a gravar no ficheiro
$string_encoded = iconv( mb_detect_encoding( $dados ), 'Windows-1252', $dados );

// Escrever no ficheiro
$file = fopen( "meu_texto.txt", "w+" );
fwrite( $file, $string_encoded );
fclose( $file );
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode escrever o arquivo adicionando as quebras de linha manualmente com os caracteres `#13 + #10` usando a função `chr()`.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, Wellington.
Tentei da forma que você sugeriu e mesmo assim não obtive o resultado que esperava. Mesmo passando os caracteres em ascii, meu arquivo está no formato UNIX, sendo assim, ele só escreve o **LF** na quebra de linha, se eu alterar o formato do arquivo pelo notepad++ para DOS/Windows ele escreve **CRLF**, é desta forma que eu espero que o arquivo seja gerado.